# SATA Power Pin #6 Broken - Will it still temporarily work?

Tags: ssd, sata

While transplanting my PC into a new case, I had an attack of the Catzilla - which caused the SATA power connector on my Samsung SSD to get broken. The pins are exposed, but the plastic 'backer' is snapped off.  Pin #6 doesn't appear to be soldered down anymore.  According to the SATA spec, pin 4, 5 and 6 are listed as common Ground.  I am going to replace this drive, but I do want to salvage the data off this drive.

Will the drive likely still work, even if only long enough to clone it - or will I start the thing (and my cloning gizmo) on fire?  If this was a larger drive, I'd try to just solder a SATA connector onto it or transplant a new SATA connector off a dead drive onto it.  If I can't save it, its going to be a serious PITA to recover everything one-by-one.

Comment: If the data connector is OK, I see no problem with soldering as a last resort solution. You can usually open SSDs’ case quite easily.

Comment: Daniel B - I will definitely keep that in mind.  Reality is that I just need to keep it running just long enough to clone it to a new drive.  If I can't, then the data on it isn't worth the time.  The only pain will be retrieving my Windows 10 license.  Everything else is cloud purchases and software I can install again.

Comment: If you logged in with your Microsoft account to activate your computer, your license should be attached to your account and you won't need to get anything off the SSD